# liquibase defaultvalue sys_guid

Tags: oracle, uuid, liquibase, default-value

how can i make a column default to SYS_GUID()using liquibase? i tried

```
                                {
                                "column": {
                                    "name": "ID",
                                    "type": "varchar(32)",
                                    "constraints": {
                                        "nullable": false,
                                        "primariKey": true,
                                        "unique": true,
                                        "defaultValueComputed": "SYS_GUID()"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
```

also tried changing sys guid to uuid

```
                                    "column": {
                                    "name": "ID",
                                    "type": "varchar(32)"                                        
                                    "constraints": {
                                        "nullable": false,
                                        "primariKey": true,
                                        "unique": true,
                                        "defaultValueComputed": "UUID"
                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for the dumb question, it was like this:

```
                                    "column": {
                                    "name": "ID",
                                    "type": "varchar(32)",
                                    "defaultValueComputed": "SYS_GUID()",
                                    "constraints": {
                                        "nullable": false,
                                        "primariKey": true,
                                        "unique": true
                                    }
                                }
```

i was dumb enough to put the default in the constraints